# Can anyone please suggest how to easy track app button clicks using firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have multiple `buttons(actions)`, that I would like to track, just need example of structure, how do I properly reference everything.

For example, I have this button in main activity, and when I run emulator I get:

> `onClcklistner` cannot be converted to context.

ps - bit new to the whole game.

```
 final Button adButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
    adButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
            mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            mFirebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "Add Button");
            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "adButton");
            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "Button");
            mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);

        }
```

Comment: See this reference https://github.com/rohitksingh/Bulucu/blob/ef0e5bfd7b446123726185484a943b90ef7eec6d/Bulucu/app/src/main/java/com/freewifi/rohksin/freewifi/Activities/HomePageActivity.java#L97 .

Comment: Can you please add the whole error log please?